# Dynamic menu from mysql PHP

Tags: php, arrays, menu

Hey everyone, I am stuck with arrays. I was trying to make a menu from my sql but I keep failing.

This is the response:

```
Id - 3 , Name - Axle, con - 7, Desc - thin
Id - 4 , Name - Axle, con - 7, Desc - flat
Id - 5 , Name - Ball, con - 8, Desc - round
Id - 6 , Name - Ball, con - 8, Desc - hard
```

Basicly , its a join and are connected by con and partId, same con has the same name .

All want it to do is this:

```
<ul>

<li>Axle

          <li>thin</li>
          <li>flat</li>
</li>

<li>Ball

         <li>round</li>
         <li>hard</li>

</li>
</ul>
```

I tried this out but got nothing
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Simple-Mysql-PHP-Menu.html#1

Can someone guide me in the right direction?
Thank you

UPDATE
//////////

Ok thanks for the replies but I still cant get ti to work.
I cant get rid of the double Axles .

Comment: Never seen such formatting of a sql table.

Answer (score 1):

First I would declare an empty array for the navigation.

```
$part_array = array();
```

First I would loop through the array and combine items based on the part name.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($mysql_result_array as $part) {
   $part_array[$part['ID'] = $part['ID'];
   $part_array[$part['ID']['Name'] = $part['Name'];
   $part_array[$part['ID']['parts'] = $part;
   $counter++;
}
```

Now you have all of the parts separately, but contained within the same ID of an array. From here I would loop through each part of the $part_array and echo each part within that ID out as it's own list item.

```
    foreach($part_array as $list_item) {
        echo '<ul id="<?=$part_item['ID']?>">';
        echo '<li id="'.$list_item['Name'].'">'.$list_item['Name'];
        echo '<ul id="'.$list_item['Name'].'_sub">';
        foreach($list_item['parts'] as $list_item_part) {
            echo '<li id="'.$list_item['Name'].'_.'.$list_item['Desc'].'"><a href="/part.php?id='.$list_item['conn'].'">'.$list_item['Desc'].'</a>';
        }
    }
```

It may not be the most efficient or the most elegant, but hopefully it gives you the idea.

Comment: Hi, same as the other answer, this doesnt seem to work!, thanks though

Comment: Can you post your MySQL code? (the query, the result array creation, etc.) I'll try to see if I can modify that to fit your results.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to iterate over the result list and separate the main menu entries from the secondary titles:

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
    extract($row);   // take care that $row entries can't overwrite vars
    $main[$Id] = $Name;
    $sub[$Id][] = $Desc;
}
```

Then iterate over the $main list and for each entry also run through the $sub list:

```
foreach ($main as $Id => $Name) {
    print "<li>$Name";
    print "<ul>";
    foreach ($sub[$Id] as $Desc) {
        print "<li>$Desc";
    }
    print "</ul></li>";
}
```

If you have a nested list (your question didn't say so), then you would need a recursive function instead of the simple loop.